# РHP и выполнение консольных команд

Tags: php, linux

Мне нужно выполнить команду из консоли, которая запрашивает доп параметры - пароль, подтверждение пароля.

Как в ту же сессию консоли отправить новые данные?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

Comment: Уточните что именно вы хотите сделать? Для запроса пользовательских данных можно использовать readline, например.

Comment: ```echo "Введите пароль: "; $input = fgets(STDIN); echo $input; ```